# How can I have access to the Drupal 7 $database variable?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have written some php/mysql queries inside node.tpl.php and page.tpl.php.

The username and password that these pages use to connect to MySQL are specified within the files.

Instead of doing this, I would like to be able to use the MySQL connection settings that are defined in Drupal's settings.php file.

I am trying, unsuccessfully include the settings.php file into node.tpl.php and page.tpl.php.

```
<?php include("sites/default/settings.php") ?>
```

Then I am trying to access the $databases array from settings.php like this:

```
$databases['default']['default']['username']
```

The $databases array has this structure:

```
$databases = array (
                   'default' => 
                        array (
                          'default' => 
                               array (
                                    'database' => 'sdnndr',
                                    'username' => 'root',
                                    'password' => '',
                                    'host' => 'localhost',
                                    'port' => '',
                                    'driver' => 'mysql',
                                    'prefix' => '',
                                ),
                        ),
              );
```

My approach is not working. Can anyone suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me count the way you are doing this wrong. You do not write queries into templates. Never. Because if you change looks later you would lose your logic. Put them in modules where they belong. You do need not include settings, it's already included. You do not write MySQL queries because they are insecure, instead you use http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/group/database/7 which encourages (and in some case even enforces) security.

Comment: It would probably be useful if you actually suggested what to do instead rather than just criticise. But yes, all the above is still true.

Comment: Given there's no *actual* problem to solve, how could I suggest a more appropriate solution beyond pointing out Drupal's database API?

Comment: You don't explain _why_ its bad and give no indication as to what to do instead. There's nothing more frustrating than finding a question that's applicable to your use case but the answer gives little clarification. Giving a link is all good and well but for someone with little experience (especially considering its Drupal) its almost next to useless. Of course I can see that you might not have wanted to spend unnecessary time writing up an in-depth explanation of your answer but just a little guidance could be very helpful to pointing some in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Along with what chx says

> Let me count the way you are doing this wrong. You do not write queries into templates. Never. You do not include settings, it's already included. You do not write MySQL queries you use

in your theme's template.php file you have access to most of the variables coming to page.tpl.php.  use

```
hook_preprocess(&$variables, $hook);
```

Then dump or dsm($variables);  (devel module must be installed).

If you really need to query the database, create a small module and in the .module file use drupal functions to query the database. There also you dont have to worry about connecting to database, that is done in the bootstrap process.