# To Connect to MYSQL - How to access database array in setting.php

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I need to connect to my database in php file in drupal 7. Each time I move from local server to development server, I have seen `setting.php` file which have array of database.

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'my_db',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

How do I aceess this database array in drupal 7 to use it connecting to database

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','my_db');
```

I am looking for drupal way to achieve this.

Thanks for Help

Comment: check [this link](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65770/i-need-to-load-db-configuration-dynamically-in-drupal-7),hopes help u.

Comment: @leo - Thanks for the quick reply but that ans just tells me how to dynamically set the $database array in `setting.php` where as I am looking for accessing the '$database' array so that I can use it to MYSQL connection.....Sorry for any confusion If I was not clear .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** My mind was in the wrong programming language. Sorry.

**EDIT Again:** Removing standard PHP DB query methods in favor of Drupal methods.

According to the [document](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/group/database/7) you provided, you do not need to create a database connection within the Drupal environment. You can instead use methods provided by Drupal to utilize the existing database connection to execute your queries.

You have two main methods available to you:

1. [db_query()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7) - good for non-limited results
2. [db_query_range()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query_range/7) - equivalent to adding "LIMIT X, Y" in sql

*From the Drupal Documentation, the following SQL:

```
SELECT n.nid, n.title, n.created FROM node n WHERE n.uid = $uid
  ORDER BY n.created DESC LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Is best executed in Drupal as:

```
$result = db_query_range('SELECT n.nid, n.title, n.created
  FROM {node} n WHERE n.uid = :uid
  ORDER BY n.created DESC', 0, 10, array(':uid' => $uid));
```

Again, it might be best to refer to this [document](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/group/database/7), and use the Drupal method.

Comment: Do I need to include `setting.php` ... What is the drupal way to do it  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146173/how-can-i-have-access-to-the-drupal-7-database-variable

Comment: Hey, after reading the article you referenced, it looks like Drupal has its own way of doing things.

They claim you can use the database connection created by Drupal by using "db_query()" or "db_query_range()" without doing anything else. Have you tried your SQL in those functions?

Comment: Trying Now !!! I am little new to Drupal I did not know this It seems that we can access database in Drupal without making connection ... I think it might work ..let me try !!!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
    include "settings.php";
    $con=mysqli_connect($databases['default']['default']['host'],$databases['default']['default']['username'],$databases['default']['default']['password'],$databases['default']['default']['database']);
```

You just have to get those values out of the array.

Comment: I am not sure if i need to include `setting.php` how to do it Drupal way ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146173/how-can-i-have-access-to-the-drupal-7-database-variable

Comment: Looks like some people are trying "include" with a URL to the file, you can look at other methods people have used here:
https://groups.drupal.org/node/17715

Comment: A comment from there that appears to be the consensus:


"My coworker actually figured it out as I was mulling over this too.

Do this, in your themes directory, create a new directory called "includes" then as your php files, make sure they have extension ".inc"
 So:
 /sites/all/themes/Your_theme/includes
 And then create your files:
 /sites/all/themes/Your_theme/includes/file-you-want-in-block.inc

Now, do this:

<? include "." . base_path() . path_to_theme() . "/includes/file-you-want-in-block.inc"; ?>

Don't know why it has to be like this, but it works :) Hope this helps you all"

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in setting up an RSS feed to dynamically utilize the database's constants as stored in settings.php in Drupal 7. I needed to grab the information in the $databases array in that file dynamically. Here's how I solved it (Running PHP 5.3).

```
$INC_DIR = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "/sites/default/";
include($INC_DIR. "settings.php"); 

$connection = @mysql_connect($databases['default']['default']['host'],$databases['default']['default']['username'],$databases['default']['default']['password'])
or die ('Could not connect to database');

mysql_select_db($databases['default']['default']['database'])
or die ('Could not select database');
```

The first two lines solve the problem of making different folders/changing file structures and just points your script at the file, you just aim "/sites/default/" from your document root if you have the file somewhere else, then the include statement grabs the actual file information so you can use it further down in your script.

The $connection script is straightforward as well, giving your login to the server, then selecting the database, using the $databases array values that you've accessed via the above referenced include statement to get into the database so the RSS code can run.

This RSS feed has been my first real project in PHP and it's been really fun and challenging, and I'm looking forward to more coding adventures.